# My Stack Snippet doesn't always work

Tags: support, stack-snippets

The Stack Snippet I included in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690828/url-createobjecturl-is-not-a-function-js-error-in-page-from-net-core-but-not) sometimes produces the QR code as expected, but sometimes throws an error.

When I was preparing the code snippet, it worked well. But now, after it has been posted, it isn't working reliably.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: For whatever it's worth, it reliably generates the QR code for me (Safari on OS X and Waterfox on Win 7).

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sometimes the QR code is generated, mostly this error. "message": "Uncaught TypeError: url.createObjectURL is not a function",

Answer (score 1):

So your original problem is that the browser throws an error while developing and testing this code. You then decided to ask a question using the same code, and the error is reproducible using Stack Snippets.

So far so good, but why would this be a *problem* with Stack Snippets? If this issue occurs while running your original code as well as when running it in a snippet, then obviously the snippet part isn't relevant.

The problem is in your code, and it most likely is that `window.URL` is (sometimes) overwritten.

Comment: I think there is some configuration issues with my pc.

Comment: Caster  Thanks, going to remove this.

Comment: Just be sure to update your question on main. :)

Comment: Well if you're _not_ going to remove it, let me undelete my answer.

Comment: I didn't notice the upvote.